# R: text of legend falls outside of plot when exporting to PDF

Tags: r, plot, legend

When I add a legend to my R plot (using the `legend()` function), then it works in Rstudio, but when I export the plot as a PDF with a different size, then sometimes the text inside the legend is larger than the legend box itself.

[image]

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

If I export the image with a larger width, then the legend box becomes larger too and manages to contain its text, but this is silly: I want the legend box and its text to automatically adjust to whatever width I choose, no matter how small it is.

And please don't recommend `ggplot2`.

Comment: How are you exporting? Are you using `pdf()`? `cairo_pdf`? The RStudio buttons for Export > Save as PDF? Something else?

Comment: The Rstudio buttons. Then that window pops up where you can set the width and the height.

Comment: Saving the plot with `pdf()` might work better.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gregor said - you should use `pdf()`. I am merely adding his suggestion as an answer. Your code would be something like this:

```
pdf("picture.pdf", width=6, height=6)
plot(...)
legend(...)
dev.off()
```

Where `pdf()` opens a new device for plotting (of course you have to set file name as well as dimensions according to your needs), and `dev.off()` closes the device writing everything to a file.

I am not sure what causes the issue with legend in R-studio. But on my machine I noticed that legends sometimes have issues with updating after resizing the device. Probably this is something related.